# Looking for a gtk equivalent of ark

Tags: linux, gtk, zip, gzip, tar

Does there exist a GTK equivalent (or improvement) of the Linux archiving tool known as Ark? If so, where might it be found; and if not, how well-received might be a new project which acts as a front-end to tar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called File Roller, or "Archive Manager" in the menu.

Comment: Thank you! File Roller is at [fileroller.sourceforge.net](http://fileroller.sourceforge.net/), for what it's worth. I have found two other front-ends to GNU command-line archiving tools, namely [PeaZip](http://peazip.sourceforge.net/peazip-linux.html) and [Xarchiver](http://xarchiver.sourceforge.net/) (circa 2009).

Comment: File Roller requires libgnome, whereas Xarchiver does not.